# Taking the derivative of integral with two functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Solve: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left({\Large\int} _{1}^{e^x} \ f(t) g(t)\,dt\right)$

Here I know have to find out th second derivative which is $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left({\Large\int} _{1}^{e^x} \ f(t) g(t)\,dt\right)\right)$

If I just have the function $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left({\Large\int} _{1}^{e^x} \ f(t)\,dt\right)\right)$  I can easily find it out using the fundamental theorem of calculus but here I have g(t) too. What can I do for this?

Comment: If you can calculate it for a single function $f(t)$, why not set $f(t)g(t)=h(t)$ and using that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int_1^{e^x} f(t)g(t) \ dt\\
\frac {d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{e^x} f(t)g(t) \ dt\right)\\
\frac {d}{dx}\big(f(e^x)g(e^x)e^x\big)$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Now you just need to properly apply the product rule and chain rule.

$f'(e^x)g(e^x)e^{2x}+f(e^x)g'(e^x)e^{2x}+ f(e^x)g(e^x)e^x$

Comment: I think you should use $f\left(t\right)g\left(t\right)dt$ within the integrals of your first $2$ lines, as is done in the question, to avoid potential confusion with the same variable, i.e., $x$, having $2$ different meanings within the same equations!

Comment: It doesn't actually change anything, but I agree that it is more clear.

Comment: I agree it doesn't change anything. Thanks for making the change.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

($\int_1^{e^x} f(t)g(t) dt )^{'} = f(e^x)g(e^x)*(e^{x})'$

You can continue from here to get a second derivative of the function defined as the integral simply derivating $f(e^x)g(e^x)$

Comment: Chain rule!  $\frac {d}{dx} \int_1^{e^x} f(t)g(t)\ dt = f(e^x)g(e^x)\frac {d}{dx} e^x$!

Comment: You are right. I've missed the derivative of $e^{x}$